# jQuery UI datepicker date issue

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am using below code for getting date , But I faced some weird issue for some users getting

> Exception NaN-NaN-NaN Value, The string was not recognized as a valid DateTime.
> There is an unknown word starting at index 0.

```
var date = new Date();
    var currentMonth = date.getMonth();
    var currentDate = date.getDate();
    var currentYear = date.getFullYear();
    $(function () {
        $('.ui-datepicker').addClass('notranslate');
        $("[id*=txtDate]").datepicker({
            maxDate: new Date(currentYear, currentMonth, currentDate),
            dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            yearRange: '1900:+0' ,
            onSelect: function (dateText) {

                var d = new Date();
                var currentyear = d.getFullYear();
                var txt = $.trim($('#txtDate').val());
                var Seldate = new Date(txt);
                var selYear = Seldate.getFullYear();
                var YearCompare = currentyear - selYear;
                if (YearCompare < 15) {
                    alert('DOB should be grated than 15');
                    $('#txtDate').val("");
                    return false;
                }
                else
                {
                    $('#hdnDate').val(dateText);
                    $("#txtDate").val($('#hdnDate').val());
                }
            }
        });
        //$("input").checkboxradio();
    });
```

Comment: On what line do you get the exception?

Comment: Actually I want to know-how can i get this error after button click (NAN-NAN-NAN),

Comment: It's working some cases, but some cases getting error like NAN-NAN-NAN value

Answer (score 1):

When getting the date from a date picker don't use `$("#input").val()` - instead, use the datepicker API to get a date object directly:

```
$("#txtDate").datepicker("getDate");
```

> https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-getDate

Comment: If this helps you, please consider accepting as the answer. Thanks.